# ngTable / Angular with external JSON data, buttons not showing

Tags: json, angularjs, ngtable

I know there's quite a lot of info already on stackoverflow regarding ngTable/AngularJS, but I tried everything, and it just doesn't work.

my html is this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sequencing experiments overview</title>
    <script src="/LIMS/angular-1.2.14/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/LIMS/js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="/LIMS/ng-table-master/ng-table.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/LIMS/ng-table-master/ng-table.css" />
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.0.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/LIMS/style.css" />
</head>

<body ng-app="dataOverview" ng-controller="searchCtrl">

    <div>

        Search: <input ng-model="query">

        <p><strong>Page:</strong> {{tableParams.page()}}
        <p><strong>Count per page:</strong> {{tableParams.count()}}

        <table ng-table="tableParams"  class="table">
            <tr ng-repeat="exp in $data | filter:query">
                <td data-title="'id'">
                    {{exp.id}}
                </td>
                <td data-title="'name'" sortable ="'name'">
                    {{exp.name}}
                </td>
                <td data-title="'Type'">
                    {{exp.type}}
                </td>           
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>  

</body>
</html>
```

my controller.js file is this:

```
var dataOverview = angular.module('dataOverview', ['ngTable']);

dataOverview.controller('searchCtrl', function searchCtrl($scope, $http, ngTableParams) {

$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
page: 1,            // show first page
count: 5           // count per page
},{
getData: function($defer,params) {

  $http.get('/LIMS/index_query.php').
    success(function(data, status) {
      var orderedData = data;
      $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(),params.page() * params.count()));
    })
  }
 })
});
```

The index_query.php returns a valid JSON object queried from a MySQL DB (will not show this here).

So, this code is almost ok i guess. It displays a table with columns and values from the DB. I can filter using the value in the filter box. However, it only shows 5 rows, and there are no buttons to go to the next 5 rows or increase the number of rows on the page. As described  on the ngTable page (http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/1).

When checking console with firebug, I see an 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined ' error. I assume it;s an error populating the array which should build the buttons to go from 1 page with 5 records to another? I wasted 10h on this today, so please enlighten me, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Ok, you will not belief this. In a desperate attempt, I tried reverting to an older version of ngTable instead of using the latest version.

    <!--<script src="/LIMS/ng-table-master/ng-table.js"></script>-->
        
    <script data-require="ng-table@*" data-semver="0.3.0" src="http://bazalt-cms.com/assets/ng-table/0.3.0/ng-table.js"></script>

fixed everything for me...

Comment: could you make answer to yourself to close question